# Skyrim Dawnguard problem

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I was doing the Dawnguard quest and I chose to be a vampire, but I went back and played as Dawnguard. I was walking when all of a sudden it said "*Your vampire blood boils in the sunlight*." So I checked my powers and I didn't have the power to take the Vampire Form, or whatever, but I have the vampire abilities Vampire's Sight and Vampire's Servant. I took off Miraak's Mask and my eyes are all yellow. This is after I went back to Fort Dawnguard after choosing not to be a vampire, and the leader said nothing and just advanced the quest.
Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: What do you mean you "went back"? Did you reload an older save (where you never were a vampire)?

Comment: Yes i went to an older save when i chose not to be a vampire

Comment: Did you take any of the Blood Potions from Castle Volkhair?  If you drink one when not a Vampire, you contract vampirism (or maybe just Sanguinare Vampiris, which will later become Vampirism).  However, there is a bug whereby if a follower (e.g. Serana) drinks one, then the script triggers and gives **you** vampirism instead of them.

Answer (score 3):

In the Dawnguard Questline, the most common enemy type encountered in the beginning are vampires. Taking damage from a vampire's health drain spell has a chance to inflict [Sanguinare Vampiris](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Sanguinare_Vampiris), a disease that will eventually progress to vampirism.

What you are experiencing is vanilla Skyrim vampirism caused by the progression of Sanguinare Vampiris. You may have contracted this disease in your 'everyday' dungeon clearing as this is a vanilla feature.

If you do not wish to reload your save, but wish to cure your vampirism, there are several ways to do so, as detailed on the [Wiki page for vampirism](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Vampirism_(Skyrim)). These include finishing the quest *Rising at Dawn,* becoming a werewolf, or console commands.

Comment: Or it's a bug. @Elan Does your character have Sanguinare Vampiris?